# Typescript error TS7053 when building an imported object with dynamic property names

Tags: typescript

I need to do create an object with dynamic property names. In brief, I have to do the following in TypeScript:

```
import * as MaterialPkg from '@mui/material'
const importObj = {};
for (const component in MaterialPkg) {
  const key = `@mui/material/${component}`;
  importObj[key] = MaterialPkg[component];
}
```

I am getting the following error when I run `tsc`:

```
src/App.tsx:44:20 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("/PATH_TO_REPO/node_modules/@mui/material/index")'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'typeof import("/PATH_TO_REPO/node_modules/@mui/material/index")'.

44   importObj[key] = MaterialPkg[component];
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried several different approaches I've found online, including using `Record`:

```
const importObj: Record<string, any> = {};
for (const component in MaterialPkg) {
  const key = `@mui/material/${component}`;
  importObj[key] = MaterialPkg[component];
}
```

I tried creating a specific type:

```
type ImportType = {
  [key: string]: any
};
const importObj: ImportType = {};
for (const component in MaterialPkg) {
  const key = `@mui/material/${component}`;
  importObj[key] = MaterialPkg[component];
}
```

I tried defining the `importObj` variable like so:

```
const importObj: { [key: string]: object } = {};
```

How can I avoid the TS7053 error here?

Comment: This kind of key-renaming is pretty difficult to type correctly without using assertions. The best I came up with would be to use Object.fromEntries/entries and assert at the end: https://tsplay.dev/W46v7N

Comment: That solved the loop I used in my example, but I also need to attach individual objects to `importObj`, such as `importObj['react'] = React` and `importObj['@mui/material'] = MaterialPkg`. Is there no way to set an arbitrary property of an object with a string key in TypeScript?

Comment: Then I would intersect the original type with `Record<string, any>`: https://tsplay.dev/N95MqN